# one search term - two sets of results with codeigniter. how to?

Tags: codeigniter

I have a search form. I would like when someone type the term, first to search trough users table and to return his name, username, e-mail etc…and next I should perform another query with the SAME search term from another table example: posts and return posts with the user name and the post.

So I have to return and display 2 sets of results. I must admit that I am totally lost, and have no idea how to proceed.

Anyone can help me with an idea how to do this with codeigniter?

Thanks in advance, Zoreli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do the two searches asycn if that what's you're looking to do.

The best and easiest way would be to do it like this:

```
$this->load->model('search');

$data['users'] = $this->search->searchUsers($searchTerm);
$data['posts'] = $this->search->searchPosts($searchTerm);

$this->load->view('yourView',$data);
```

This assumes the `search` model has the methods that search the tables. In your view, you can iterate over `$users` and `$views` to reference the returned results.